# Create transaction history in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have created a basic calculator in jQuery Mobile which calculates bill amount per person when entered the bill amount and the number of people.
I'd like to create another page to show the history of the calculation done.
Can you please suggest some tutorials or learning material which i can refer to understand the concept and how to construct it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any particular tutorial or learning material that talks specifically about doing what you are doing but there are many tutorials that do talk about saving content via jQuery. What I'm generally getting at is that upon the end of the calculation you'll save the results to a DB or file and then on the other page you'd retrieve this information and show it.

Here is just one link ([Save data is jQuery and .Net](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c4cfca/how-to-save-data-into-database-using-jquery-and-json-in-asp/)) that uses .Net to a DB. If you need to save to file it is similar but back end is different. There are many other choices just doing a search on saving via jQuery so you'll need to choose the one that makes the most sense to you.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. That's what i'm after. Thanks for your advise. I will go through this. Cheers.